# In Hadoop, what happens when intermediate data (i.e. mapper spill output) is lost?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, data-loss

Hadoop stores intermediate data - spilled mapper outputs into a local disk, as specified by the setting `mapreduce.cluster.local.dir` in [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml).

So let's say the Hadoop job is halfway through the reduce phase, and a machine in the cluster dies. This means that:

1. all the progress/data on the reducer tasks is lost
2. all the intermediate mapper output data stored on that machine's local filesystem is lost
3. you have to rerun all the mappers whose output data was lost in (2), and then redo the Shuffle phase to get all the data into the reducers that died in (1), and then of course rerun the reducer tasks.

My question is this:

- Is this reasoning correct? And does it mean when even 1 machine fails in a Hadoop job, you are essentially doubling the total job run time?
- If machine failures are common, for example if you are running on Spot Instances (on AWS or otherwise) which are frequently interrupted, does it make sense to store intermediate output not on the local filesystem, but on HDFS?
- Does Hadoop know to rerun the mappers that lost their output? If other reducers were still fetching data from those mappers when they died, will they pause execution?

Thanks,

Arwin

Comment: Not sure I follow "doubling the total time". Especially if you are running hundreds of mappers or reducers, and only a handful need to be restarted due to any failure or error. It's less than half, so the total time wouldn't be double. And storing results to HDFS would make it slower to wait for these results, and that data would never be swept away without an external process doing that... This isn't specific to just mapreduce either, but also Tez or Spark

Comment: @cricket_007 If your cluster can run most or all of your task containers at the same time (map or reduce), and the map->shuffle->reduce takes 6 hours, then a machine failure would cause the job to run an additional 6 hours. You are right though, this is an assumption.

Comment: Generally, all of those aren't running on the same machine. But sure, if they were, then you would need to repeat whatever work was trying to be done

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, you'd only need to rerun the tasks lost on that machine (not all) but the rest of the job needs to wait for them to finish right? I'm also curious, if the failure happened during the shuffle phase, would all of the reducers pause because they didn't finish fetching the output from the mappers that are now lost?

Comment: It does need to wait, but usually more than one job for the same task is running anyway for resiliency, or at least, that's configurable through some settings. In a multi stage job, reducers do not all have to wait for mappers and shuffles to finish